# LINQ Queries work in LINQ Pad not in VS

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query which I created in LINQPad (https://www.linqpad.net/) tested and all worked fine.

```
var UserEvents = from e in _context.Events
                 join s in _context.Shifts on e.ShiftID equals s.SHFID
                 where e.UID == userID
                 select new UserEvents
                 {
                     EVTID = e.EVTID,
                     UID = e.UID,
                     ShiftID = e.ShiftID,
                     EVTDate = e.EVTDate,
                     Notes = e.Notes,
                     AreaID = s.Area.AreaID,
                     AreaDesc = s.Area.AreaDesc,
                     CPYDesc = s.Area.Company.CPYDesc,
                     StartTime = s.StartTime,
                     EndTime = s.EndTime,
                     RequiredResources = s.RequiredResources,
                     ShiftDesc = s.ShiftDesc,
                     ShiftDayOfWeek = s.ShiftDayOfWeek
                 };
```

When I moved it over to **VS it complained that Shift did not have a definition for Area.**

This is true Shift.cs does not contain an explicit declaration to Area as that is specified in Areas with a `public List<Shift> SHFID { get; set; }`

Now I am quite stuck trying to figure out how to make this query work without stuffing up my table structure (Using code first Entity.Framework)

## Shifts.cs

```
public class Shift
{
    [Key]
    public int SHFID { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
    public int RequiredResources { get; set; }
    public string ShiftDesc { get; set; }
    public string ShiftDayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftExDateStart { get; set; }
    public DateTime ShiftExDateEnd { get; set; }
    public int ShiftExLevel { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ShiftExStartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan ShiftExEndTime { get; set; }
}
```

## Area.cs

```
public class Area
{
    [Key]
    public int AreaID { get; set; }
    public string AreaDesc { get; set; }
    public Boolean AreaActive { get; set; }
    public DateTime AreaCreatedDate { get; set; }
    public List<Shift> SHFID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Well, add a property `Area` to `Shift`. EF should pick it up as a 1:n (Area : Shift) relation between both classes and translate it into a SQL join.

Comment: Looks like a good idea, as for the declaration. Just declare an int Area? or declare it some other way?

Comment: I suggest you do some reading on [navigation properties in Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj713564.aspx). There's too much to explain here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Well, add a property Area to Shift. EF should pick it up as a 1:n (Area : Shift) relation between both classes and translate it into a SQL join. – Gert Arnold

This fixed my issue,

Adding `public Area Area { get; set; }` to my class allowed the navigation that I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What basically are you trying to do is get the Area property of the shift object 
`AreaID = s.Area.AreaID,`
Which is wrong, since your data models say that an area can contain shifts which is 1->n relationship. You need to add another join here to areas on e.AreaId and use that object to get area's properties

```
var UserEvents = from e in _context.Events
                 join s in _context.Shifts on e.ShiftID equals s.SHFID
                 join a in _context.Areas on e.AreaID equals a.AreaID
                 where e.UID == userID
                 select new UserEvents
                 {
                     EVTID = e.EVTID,
                     UID = e.UID,
                     ShiftID = e.ShiftID,
                     EVTDate = e.EVTDate,
                     Notes = e.Notes,
                     AreaID = a.AreaID,
                     AreaDesc = a.AreaDesc,
                     CPYDesc = a.Company.CPYDesc,
                     StartTime = s.StartTime,
                     EndTime = s.EndTime,
                     RequiredResources = s.RequiredResources,
                     ShiftDesc = s.ShiftDesc,
                     ShiftDayOfWeek = s.ShiftDayOfWeek
                 };
```

Comment: Are you suggesting that navigation from this point is impossible? I thought the whole idea of LINQ was to enable navigation as opposed to the older joining method. I have concluded that there would be a way to edit the Area or Shift definition that would allow two way navigation as is possible at the database level using LINQPad.

Comment: To achieve what you want , you'll need to set up virtual objects for Shifts in areas (called lazy loading) and that's not even up to linq. Right now, you'll need to add another join.

Comment: You'll also need to insert ForeignKey attributes for relations, don't forget to check the edited answer, your updated query should look something like that. I just don't think you can get the company from the area object if the area object is exact as you have provided it here.

Comment: No Good, it complains about the join using SHFID to Shifts in Area. There has to be a way to navigate this... I think there must be something I can do in the classes to allow it as it does work when I use LINQ at the database level. CS1941 The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.